# Problema con jquery evitar que se recargue la pagina de un login?

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente jquery para validar los datos de entrada de un login, pero muestro el msj y se vuelve a recargar la pagina y el return false y e.preventDefault() no hace su funcion.

```
      $('#btnlog').closest('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#btnlog').attr('disabled', true);
            this.submit(); // ahora hace el submit de tu formulario.
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var contraseña = $('#contraseña').val();

            if (email == '' || contraseña == '') {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#msjviewbag').empty();
                $('.espacio').hide();
                $('#btnlog').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#errorlog').html('Los Campos No Deben Estar Vacios');
                return false;
            }

            if ($('#email').val() != '') {
                if ($('#email').val().indexOf('@@', 0) == -1 || $('#email').val().indexOf('.', 0) == -1) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#msjviewbag').empty();
                    $('.espacio').hide();
                    $('#btnlog').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('#errorlog').html('El Formato de Email No es Correcto');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Una cosa que no entiendo es por que utilizas el preventDefault() dentro de los ifs que tienes, por otro lado, el que esta al inicio intenta adjuntar otra lienea utilizando stopProppagation().

Comment: colocaste el `this.submit();` ese envia el formulario, solo quitalo o comentalo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> El error es que estas forzando el envio del formulario al hacer `this.submit();`

Una solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
  $('#btnlog').closest('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        $('#btnlog').attr('disabled', true);
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var contraseña = $('#contraseña').val();
        var error = '';

        if (email == '' || contraseña == '') {
            error = 'Los Campos No Deben Estar Vacios';
        }

        if ($('#email').val().indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || $('#email').val().indexOf('.', 0) == -1) {
            error = 'El Formato de Email No es Correcto';
        }

        if (error) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#msjviewbag').empty();
            $('.espacio').hide();
            $('#btnlog').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#errorlog').html(error);
            return false;
        }
    });
```